# Caching Https response

Tags: caching, https, http-caching

How to cache **https** response, Is it really safe to cache it in case of an authenticated url.

Answer (score 0):

Make your server use the `Cache-Control: public` for pages where it's appropriate.

Regarding security, don't cache sensitive data (so don't put that header on resources that shouldn't be cached).

Comment: Cache-Control: private for caching authenticated pages. Also can i use must-revalidate so that i can validate the access permission.